# what this line of android code means?

Tags: android, fragment

```
mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

what are the meaning of this line?
why there are those many = ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to understand if it was written like this:

```
mDualPane = ((detailsFrame != null) && 
             (detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE));
```

Which breaks it into a single `boolean` value which is returned from the `AND` (`&&`) of the two conditions above:

```
detailsFrame != null
```

And

```
detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
```

We first check that `detailsFrame != null` in order to avoid NPE - only then we check that it's visible by calling: `detailsFrame.getVisibility()`

Answer (score 2):

It meas that

if detailsFrame **NOT** null
**AND**
detailsFrame.getVisibility() **IS** View.VISIBLE

then mDualPane equals `true` else mDualPane will equal `false`.

Comment: Where does `else` come into it?

Comment: I dont think it is a tenary statement... I think a tenary statement is like Value = a ? b: c;

Comment: @Squonk, my bad. I really misread it at first. I fixed my answer right as you commented. :-p

Comment: yep, I misread it for a tenary also - but double checked before I answered :)

Comment: @0909EM I reread it <em>after</em> I posted my answer and realized I missed the ball. Fortunately, a mild change and I fixed it. :-p

Answer (score 1):

```
mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

`mDualPane` will be `true` when `detailsFrame` is visible.

Comment: yea. i left that out as its implied.

Answer (score 0):

mDualPane appears to be a boolean.

The line means mDualPane will be true if detailsFrame is not null and details frame is Visible